# WebGL rotate function

Tags: rotation, webgl

I'm trying to understand the rotation of the matrices using WebGL.

I got this **mat4()** matrix and I have to apply these transformations :

```
m = translate(torsoHeight+1*headHeight, 5, 0.0); 
m = mult(m, rotate(theta[head1Id], 1, 0, 0))
m = mult(m, rotate(theta[head2Id], 0, 1, 0));
m = mult(m, translate(0.0, -0.5*headHeight, 0.0));
figure[headId] = createNode( m, head, leftUpperArmId, null);
break;
```

I did not understand exactly how the mult function works. The first parameter is my matrix.
The **theta[]** is built in this way :

```
var theta = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 180, 0, 0];
```

and

```
var headId  = 1;
var head1Id = 1;
var head2Id = 10;
```

Am I right if I thought that the second parameter is another matrix build with the rotate() function ? In  this case how does the rotate function work ?

Comment: [I'd recommend these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html). The ones before explain rotation, the ones after expand to 3D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rotate` and `translate` are functions that create matrices.

`rotate` looks like it's arguments are `(angle, vectorx, vectory, vectorz)` to create a matrix rotating points around the given vectory.

`mult` is the standard mathematical multiplication for 4x4 matrices.

You probably should dig in linear algebra tutorials such as https://open.gl/transformations